# Limiting Access to API Gateway (and AWS Lambda) in a package

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We have a package that we share with out customers. In the package, we have a chunk of code that does HTTP Request callouts to our central API Gateway. As of now, our API Gateway is open and accepts requests from everywhere, which is not good. I want to limit access to our users who would be using our software. The only solution I have found is using IAM and providing authorization that would require us to include our Access Keys in the package. Our users can install our package in any environment they want and we have no control over that environment. So I think a viable option is to create a generic user policy with minimal access to allow our users to call our API Gateway. However, putting access key in the code doesn't seem like a good idea. Another option is to provider our customers with access keys but that also has overhead. What is a better alternative that is more secure and easy to maintain?

Comment: Take a look at API Keys in the Amazon API Gateway Console screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use built-in API Gateway API Key functionality when IAM policies aren't possible.**

So long as your clients could be on any infrastructure, versus limited to AWS, the API Gateway service provides a generic API key solution, which allows you to restrict client traffic to your API Gateway by enforcing that client requests include API keys. This API key interface is part of their "[API Usage Plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)" feature.

[This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html#api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console) explains how to use the console to set up an API Gateway to enforce that client traffic bears an API key:

> To set up API keys, do the following:
>
> - Configure API methods to require an API key.
> - Create or import an API key for the API in a region.

**Your clients can implement a "secret storage" solution, in order to avoid putting their API keys into their source code.**

For sure it isn't wise for your clients to store their API Keys plain-text inside their source code. Instead, they could use a secret storage solution, to store the API keys outside of their codebase, but still give their applications access to the secret.

This article describes an example solution for secure secret storage (e.g. secure API key storage) which grants an application access to the application secret without putting the unencrypted secret into the source code. It uses Amazon KMS + Cryptex, but the same principle can be applied with other technologies: http://technologyadvice.github.io/lock-up-your-customer-accounts-give-away-the-key/